# In Fitnesse tool getting Outofmemory after executing bulk of testcases

Tags: fitnesse

I am facing one problem Fitnesse tool ,while running no.of suites in Linux machine after executing few testcases around 800 testcases it is showing as outofmemory in fit console.
Could anyone please give me some better ideas on this how to resolve this Outofmemory problems while executing more testcases.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a larger heap size when running FitNesse.  Start with the following:

```
java -Xmx500 -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8080
```

The default value is 64MB, so you can start as low as 200 and keep going up from there until your suite runs successfully.

Obviously change the port number to match your setup.